# Обмен данными между двумя python скриптами

Tags: python-3.x, многопоточность, serial

**Суть**

Первый скрипт запускается, ищет доступные последовательные порты и складывает в список, передаёт их другому скрипту, а далее перезагружается(не смог заставить **serial.tools.list_ports** искать порты в цикле).Второй скрипт принимает список и уже применяет в некоторых целях. Вопрос, как реализовать связь между скриптами, при условии, что один из них будет постоянно перезагружаться. Если есть возможность не перезагружать первый скрипт, а искать порты в цикле, так даже будет лучше

Вот пример кода:

```
import serial.tools.list_ports

port_list = []

def search_ports():
    ports = serial.tools.list_ports.comports()
    for port, desc, hwid in sorted(ports):
        port_list.append(port)

search_ports()
```

Comment: А почему бы не использовать для этого какую-нибудь примитивную БД хотя бы sqlite для примера. В теории конечно можно налепить сокетов, но нафига?

Comment: @Namerek, тип, записывать эти данные в файл и с другого скрипта его читать?

Comment: "а искать порты в цикле," - ну так ищите в цикле. В чем проблема вызывать хотя бы `search_ports()` сколько угодно раз?

Comment: Ну да, проще всего просто в файл писать и из файла читать. Но можно и в БД писать.

Comment: @vitidev, Я так понял этот модуль сканирует порты при запуске скрипта.В цикле он кидает те же порты снова и снова,хотя добавились новые

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось этот модуль верно сканирует все порты в цикле, ошибка была в последующей части кода, там я записал новые порты в другую переменную с похожим названием, которую не обновлял для виджета OptionMenu

Вот рабочий вариант:

```
import serial.tools.list_ports

port_list = []

def search_ports():
    ports = serial.tools.list_ports.comports()
    for port, desc, hwid in sorted(ports):
        port_list.append(port)

search_ports()
# появился новый порт
# используем вторую функцию
def common():
    ports = serial.tools.list_ports.comports()  #
    for port, desc, hwid in sorted(ports):  # Инициализация портов(разделение строки)
        if port_list.count(port) == 0:
            port_list.append(port)
        else:
            continue
    menu = your_option_menu["menu"]
    menu.delete(0, "end")
    for string in port_list:
        menu.add_command(label=string, command=lambda value=string:your_string_var.set(value))
    print(port_list)

common()
```